# Weird behavior in Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, performance

Firefox 42.0 on Win7 Pro x64

Since I switched to the new navigation in SO I've been seeing slow responsiveness and spikes in CPU usage.  The overall feel is of a very sluggish UI that sometimes misses clicks or takes seconds to change the mouse cursor when hovering over links.

This is happening only in Firefox and not Chrome, and only on SO and not other sites for which I don't have the new nav enabled.  I realize it's likely a problem with FF and not SO, but before I post a bug report to Mozilla it would be nice to know if someone here can suggest if a change in the new navigation scheme implementation could be related.

Here's a CPU graph showing what's happening.  The first section is when I was on meta.so composing this question. The right section shows what happened when I switched back to SO and just moused over various links.  Each time, the CPU spikes briefly to 100% of 1 core.

[image]

Suggestions on how to do further troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Plenty of SO users use FF and don't seem to have this problem.  I don't.  Time to opt out of new-nav for a while perhaps, the last release was certainly not very smooth.

Comment: Can you suggest anything I can do to track down what is eating CPU?

Comment: Not meta-and-popcorn enough, ask a question like that at superuser.com

Comment: If I had to blame someone, I would blame hardware acceleration.

Comment: "slow responsiveness" I wonder how many web developers did a double take when reading this phrase. (I didn't.)

Comment: Wait, doesn't Meta also have the new nav?

Comment: I see similar slow responsiveness in Firefox but I also keep cache disabled and have firebug running, as well as user scripts (greasemonkey). `onload` event can take quite a while to trigger sometimes

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes

Comment: what happen if you disable all your addons ?

Comment: I could not reproduce that.